# How do you build an open source Xcode project without signing?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6

I've cloned an open source Xcode OSX/Cocoa project ([SatelliteEyes](https://github.com/tomtaylor/satellite-eyes/)) and am attempting a build with Xcode 6.1.1. In the project settings, the Bundle Identifier is the project owner's, and the Signing option is *Mac App Store*. If I set the Signing option to *None*, I am still prompted for a signing identity and I cannot build the project (the *No signing identity found* dialog appears, despite having set Signing to *None*). In addition, Xcode is displaying the *No signing identity found* warning with the usual *Fix Issue* button, despite setting the Signing option to *None*.

[image]

Under *Build Settings*, I have changed the *Code Signing Identity* options for Debug and Release to *Don't Code Sign*.

Despite this, Xcode still prompts me with the *No signing identity found* dialog. Why the frack is Xcode asking for a signing identity when I've got signing turned off everywhere?

I just want to build this project and run it locally to see my changes before contributing a patch. How do I do this?

Comment: cleaned project? closed and reopened xcode? you don't need to sign an application for local builds. you can also try to check the build settings tab for any remaining signing options...

Comment: Yes, I've done the usual ceremony.

Comment: When you mention build settings, did you check target build settings as well as project build settings?

Comment: All code signing settings for both the project and target are off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've gone through this multiple times and have been able to recreate a series of steps that work. What I did:

- do **not** manually select Signing *None* under the General project settings.
- **only** set the Debug Code Signing Identity to *Don't Code Sign* under Build Settings

Same goes for any subproject targets.

In other words, I was only able to build without signing by **only** manipulating the Code Signing config under the target Build Settings configuration.

I will now walk off this momentary bout of depression.

Comment: For anyone viewing this in 2022, it looks like code signing can't be disabled.

Answer (score -3):

There are two things you can try:

Make sure you're not targeting a real device in the top left corner.

1. Unplug your iPhone/iPad
2. Change from the "iOS Device" to an iOS Simulator (iPhone 6)

Comment: This is an OSX / Cocoa project, not an iOS project.